# accessing variable in JS file between server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JS file `parameters.js` that is like the following:

```
const myJSON = {
               parameter1: 2,
               parameter2: 2.
              }
module.exports = {myJSON}
```

In `server.js` I can access it by going:

```
const {myJSON} = require('./public/js/parameters.js');
```

Now in my client, I would also like to access `myJSON`. But this doesn't seem possible.

index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src='clientScript.js' type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

clientScript.js:

```
import {myJSON} from './parameters.js';
// ...
```

This loads fine on the server side, but on the client side I get the error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './parameters.js' does not provide an export named 'myJSON'`.

When I try changing the `module.exports` syntax in parameters.js to `export {myJSON}`, it then loads fine on the client side but I instead get an error on the server side `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`.

So what is the best way to share this variable between the client and server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing your module systems.

Node.js supports CommonJS and ECMAScript modules. Browsers only support ECMAScript modules.

So use `import` and `export` (and don't use `require` and `module.exports`).

That will Just Work in the browser (keeping in mind that you have to use the URL to the module and can't use the Node.js resolution system which doesn't need file extensions).

In Node.js you need to either [enable ECMAScript modules explicitly](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) or transpile them to CommonJS with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: if there are ever >1 module systems, that means there are too many module systems :') thanks for the help this sorts things out

Answer (score -1):

The old syntax and new syntax are getting mixed up and that's creating a mess.
require is old syntax whereas **ES6** uses to **import** and **export**.

use require on both sides (if it allows you) or use import on both sides (if it allows you). Go for the same approach on both ends.

Also, use **export** from paramerters.js as well.

Hopefully, this will resolve this issue.